# Miniblog routing with MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've created an MVC 4 website and added the blogging engine Miniblog - https://github.com/madskristensen/miniblog

I have added the source into a Blog folder in the root of my MVC website and can happily browse to website.com/Blog and view the index.cshtml of the blog page. However whenever I try and view a post which would generate a URL such as website.com/blog/post/test-post It will give me a 404.

Presumably this is a routing error so have I missed some configuration settings somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the web.config supplied with the miniblog-project, there are a bunch of rewriting rules and other settings that you have to add to your web.config

Comment: Thanks, I have already copied over all the settings and rules and merged them into my web.config file.

Comment: Have you altered them to suite the changed base url for the blog? (ie /blog/ instead of /)

Comment: Yeah I have altered that in the web.config file.